# Duplicate Background Process in Unix

Tags: unix

I am facing an issue with the below code snippet when included in shell script. The shell script will be run from the Autosys.

It runs as expected and returns 1 when used on command line if one instance of the job is already running.

But when the same script is ran through the .sh file(Job on Autosys) it returns 2

```
job_cnt=`ps -ef | grep "/proj/myscript.sh param1" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`
```

For the fist run it should return 1 in variable job_cnt but it returns 2.

Comment: Search for a problem in "Autosys" because the execution of this line returns 1 in both the shell and as an .sh script launched from the system crontab.

Comment: @You are correct, it looks like Autosys problem, I just ran the .sh file from command line and the above code returns 0 but from Autosys it returns 2, its really weird. Is there any solution for this? My main moto is to identify the duplicate job submission from Autosys and hold the 2nd run. Everything is taken care except this duplicate identification.

Comment: @Venkant  Skip | wc -l and see what processes capture grep.

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba, A I mentioned in my previous comment, it returns 2 processes. I think the command being executed is also considered even though I used grep -v "grep"              `job 20566 20538 0 16:26 ? 00:00:00 /bin/bash /mypath/myfile.sh`
`job 21044 20566 0 16:27 ? 00:00:00 /bin/bash /mypath/myfile.sh`

Comment: @Venkant Where does the application come from? Grep is not on the list, there are only two calls "/ bin / bash /mypath/myfile.sh". Something is calling your script again. I do not have a "autosys" or show what your script does. So I can not replicate the problem.

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba, This issue occurs when the shell script run only from Autosys job. No other place. When I run the same shell script from command line, it goes well with just one call. I am planning to change my code to check for the duplication on the oracle SP as Autosys is causing this duplication. Thanks for trying to help me. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I didn't find a way to this issue, I just used an alternate solution and it worked well.

```
dummyfile="$data_folder/$lv_autosys_job_nm"_DUMMY.txt
dummydup="$data_folder/$lv_autosys_job_nm"_DUMMY_DUP.txt

    sleep $(( RANDOM % 10 + 10 ))
    cnt=1
    while [ -r $dummyfile ]
    do
      if [ $cnt == 1 ]; then
       /* Code to send an email*/
      cnt=2
        echo "process id:$$"> $dummydup
        chmod 755 $dummydup
      fi

      echo "Duplicate session waiting inside the loop " >> ${LOGFILE}
      sleep 30

    done
    if [ $cnt == 2 ]; then
        rm -f $dummydup
        exit 0
    fi
    echo "process id:$$"> $dummyfile
    chmod 755 $dummyfile
```

at the end before exit

```
rm -f $dummyfile
```

Edit: I forgot to mention, thanks to colleague for helping me out with the unix scripting. He was a genius in writing unix scripting.